# How do I get an Intel CS630 webcam working?

Tags: installation, webcam

I currently own a CS630 Intel R PC Camera and cannot for the life of me find anyone who would help me install it. Can you please help me?

Answer (score 1):

Thanks to various Ubuntu & Linux community, I was able to get my Intel CS630 Webcam to run with Skype and Cheese (Ubuntu 12.04 32bit) using the following commands:

```
sudo rmmod gspca_spca500;
sudo rmmod gspca_main;
sudo modprobe gspca_spca500;

sudo modprobe -r gspca_sunplus;
sudo modprobe gspca_sunplus;

LD_PRELOAD=/usr/lib/i386-linux-gnu/libv4l/v4l2convert.so skype
```

Answer (score 0):

First thing is install cheese.
Open a terminal and `sudo apt-get install cheese`

and

Follow these [instructions](https://help.ubuntu.com/community/Webcam)